# angles subtending arcs at the circumference and centre

Tags: geometry, circles

$A$ and $B$ are two points on the circumference of a circle center $O$. $C$ is a point on the major arc $AB$. Draw the lines $AC$, $BC$, $AO$, $BO$, and $CO$, extending the last line to a point $D$ inside the sector $AOB$. Prove that $\angle AOD$ is twice $\angle ACO$ and that $\angle BOD$ is twice angle $\angle BCO$. Hence show that the angle subtended by the minor arc $AB$ at the centre of the circle is twice the angle that it subtends at the circumference of the circle.

Comment: WLOG, assume $D$ is on the circumference of the circle so that $CD$ is a diameter.

Comment: i don't know what formal steps to take here

Comment: Have you drawn the diagram?

Comment: yeah, perhaps im just tired.

Comment: Do you know "the angle subtended by an arc of a circle at the centre is double the angle subtended by it at any point on the circle" ?

Comment: that proof comes after the question in my text book so i think it wants me to derive it

Comment: $\angle AOC +\angle AOD$ is a straight angle.  Triangle $OAD$ is symmetric (two edges are radii).  Using the sum of angles formula in the triangle $OAD$ you can find $\angle AOC$. ...

Comment: thanks i will have another go tomorrow